# Where does magento call prototype.js?

Tags: prototype-js

I need to optimise my site and  to do so I need to async call prototype. Does anybody know in which part of Magento the prototype start been called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usually prototype.js added in layout (app\design\frontend\your_package\your_theme\layout\page.xml)as child of "head"

```
 <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
```